# catching CTRL-C and manipulating clipboard data with wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, clipboard

My wxpython application must respond everytime user hits CTRL-C, no matter if applications frame is on top/visible but unfocussed/minimalized/under other window etc. Basically I want to know that user copied something into clipboard using CTRL-C combination - other changes in clipboard (like mouse r-click + "copy" should be ignored), than do things with data copied into clipboard. That's why I'm using pyHook and everything seems to be fine except... all code within "OnKeyboardEvent" seems to be executed before CTRL-C does its "actuall job" (copying things into clipboard), so every time I am kind of "one step back":

What happens:

```
1. user hits CTRL-C
2. my "OnKeyboardEvent" code is executed 
3. data is being copied to the clipboard (CTRL-C does its job)
```

I need to do 3. before 2. .... :)

Anyway, here's the code:

```
import wx
import pyHook
import win32clipboard

class TextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Frame', size=(300, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1) 
        self.basicText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", size=(175, -1))

        self.basicText.SetValue("Press CTRL-C")
        hm = pyHook.HookManager()
        hm.KeyDown = self.OnKeyboardEvent
        hm.HookKeyboard()

    def OnKeyboardEvent(self,event):
        if event.Ascii == 3:
            win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
            clipboarditem = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
            win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
            print clipboarditem
            self.basicText.SetValue(clipboarditem)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = TextFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Second thing wrong with code above... See this "print clipboarditem" at the end of "OnKeyboardEvent" procedure? If I delete it next command - "self.basicText.SetValue(clipboarditem)"  stops working and gives

```
line 23, in OnKeyboardEvent
self.basicText.SetValue(clipboarditem)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 13075, in SetValue
return _core_.TextEntryBase_SetValue(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

which is mind blowing for me :/

Comment: but if use uses right mouse click then "copy" ? how would you detect that?

Comment: I'm only intrested in "CTRL-C changes in clipboard" - mouse copy should not be detected at all

Comment: wx.python has its own clipboard function: https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Clipboard-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure it out but did it!

Just change key down event to key up and it works. Your callback is called when CTRL+C is released, so clipboard is already correct since CTRL+C has been processed.

(also fixed the callback returned `True` else I get a lot of exception messages)

```
import wx
import pyHook
import win32clipboard
import time


class TextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Frame', size=(300, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.basicText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", size=(175, -1))

        self.basicText.SetValue("Press CTRL-C")
        hm = pyHook.HookManager()
        hm.KeyUp = self.OnKeyboardEvent  # key up!!
        hm.HookKeyboard()


    def OnKeyboardEvent(self,event):
        if event.Ascii == 3:
            print("control c released")
            win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
            clipboarditem = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
            win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
            print("contents "+clipboarditem)
            self.basicText.SetValue(clipboarditem)
        return True

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = TextFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```